# how to create array object in loop without extra key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I am creating a array object without loop like below :

```
var data = [];
var obj = {};
obj["key1"] = 'val 1';
obj["key2"] = 'val 2';
data.push(obj);
```

The above code produce me `Array[Object]`, but when I am trying to create this in a loop like below:

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj["key1"] = 'val 1';
    obj["key2"] = 'val 2';
    data.push(obj);
}
```

It produce me `Array[]`, in that 2nd array there is an extra index. So how can I get the array like below:
`Array[Object,Object,Object]`

Comment: `It produce me Array[] , in that 2nd array there is an extra index` - what second array? what index? - your second code snippet actually produces `Array [ Object, Object, Object ]` (if len is set to 3)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: your code work fine if you want :-`Array[Object,Object,Object,]`

Comment: `in that 2nd array there is an extra index.` it clearly means that there is problem in `len` variable.show us the value of `len`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want:-`Array[Object,Object,Object]` then your code is working perfectly fine

See example:-

```js
var data = [];

var len = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var obj = {}; // put outside
    obj["key1"] = 'val 1';
    obj["key2"] = 'val 2';
    data.push(obj);
}
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

***Note:-*** I think problem is there with ***`len`*** variable because of which loop executed one more time and you get an extra index?

Check and try something like `len = len-1;` and then use it in loop

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, asuming var len is 3

```js
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj["key1"] = 'val 1';
    obj["key2"] = 'val 2';
    data.push(obj);
}
```

Give back an array with 3 objects inside. Each object has 2 values.

[Object, Object, Object]